# In Laravel 4 how to call Artisan command through web interface?

Tags: php, laravel

In [Laravel 4](https://github.com/illuminate) how to call Artisan commands through web interface?

I have tried the following

```
$command = "controller:make";
$parameters = array('name' => 'FooController');
Artisan::call($command,$parameters);
```

however I am getting this error message

```
 InvalidArgumentException: There are no commands defined in the "controller" namespace.
```

any idea?

Comment: Could you show use how you defined your command please?

Comment: unfortunately i dont know because this is a predefined command. thanks

Comment: Are you still having issues with this? I'm able to run your code without issue, and the controller is indeed created.

Answer (score 3):

There's now a bundle that does exactly this called WebArtisan, please see this page for more:

http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=10334

If you find this helpful please mark my answer.

Comment: We all know what to do with helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

Did you register your command? I have no problems at all calling a artisan command through the web using Arisan:call(). I did not install a bundle for it.

Answer (score 0):

Artisan is not designed to be called via the web.

However, if you need to, you can use [this bundle](https://github.com/joecwallace/web-artisan) which will allow you to expose Artisan to the web.

Make sure you read the bit about not using it in production, or adding some sort of password protect option!

Comment: +1 for the bit about not using it in production. Allowing Artisan to be run by just anyone is a bad bad idea.

Comment: thanks but i knew this bundle, it did not solve my problem because it is for Laravel 3 only, Laravel 4 is different.